# how to return value as array object

Tags: c#

hi try make application randomnumber and i try to return array value but i got error

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

on `b[group.Key + group.Count()];`

```
public int[] twodigi(int number)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int var = Convert.ToInt32(number);
        int[] a = new int[var];


        for (int i = 0; i < var; i++)
        {
            int randomnumber = random.Next(10, 100);
            a[i] = randomnumber;
        }

        var groups = a.GroupBy(v => v).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count());
        int[] b;   
        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            b[group.Key + group.Count()];
        }

        return b;
    }
```

Comment: _"i got error"_ What is it?

Comment: `int var = Convert.ToInt32(number);` This seems kind of pointless...even assuming a valid variable name.

Comment: @JaydipJ `var` is not keyword in C#... you may be mixing it up with some other language. It is [*contextual keyword*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/the35c6y.aspx) and can be used in given context perfectly fine. `var var = 3;`

Comment: you have already `number` parameter with datatype `int` so use it directly.
and you can't use `int var` because `var` is a keyword

Comment: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement error is this

Comment: error at  b[group.Key + group.Count()];

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov well just tried works fine Thanks for correcting me, :)

Comment: i already change var to num still error at b[group.Key + group.Count()];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope that you can try like this:

```
return a.GroupBy(v => v).Select(x=> x.Key + x.Count()).ToArray();
```

If you are expecting sum of each key and count of elements associated with that keys in the result array. Please Go through this [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S3LLm9), and let me know your result is different than this:

The method signature will be changed as like this:

```
public static int[] twodigi(int number)
{
    Random random = new Random();    
    int[] a = new int[number];
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {         
        a[i] = random.Next(10, 100);
    }

      return a.GroupBy(v => v).Select(x=> x.Key + x.Count()).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Cool HAppy to help you........!

Answer (score 0):

As others have indicated, your problem is here:

```
 int[] b;   
    foreach (var group in groups)
    {
        // What do you actually want to do with this?
        b[group.Key + group.Count()];
    }
```

The compiler is telling you that it's unclear what you intend for it to do with that value.

Also, `b` is never initialized.